# stack in convert variable to array from method

Tags: php, arrays, variables, methods

How to resolve this?

My expectation result is one, after click button detail
please help me..

```
<?php 
    $_SESSION['array1'] = array("zero","one","two");
    print_r($_SESSION['array1']);
?>
<form action="" method="post">
<input type="hidden" value="<?php print_r($_SESSION['array1']); ?>" name="detailCart"> 
<input type="submit" value="Detail" name="detail" class="detail">
</form>

<?php

    if (isset($_POST['detail'])) {
        session_start();
        print_r($_POST['detailCart']);
        echo "<br>";
        print_r($_POST['detailCart'][1]);
         // should result is one
    }
?>
```

Comment: you need to convert array to variable ? what you try ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> first thing you store your array in **SESSION** so you can get **SESSION DATA** anywhere in the form and another form no need to submit that data to externally.

**fetch data with session**

```
<?php

    if (isset($_POST['detail'])) {
      echo $_SESSION['array1'][0];
      echo $_SESSION['array1'][1];
      echo $_SESSION['array1'][2];
   }
?>
```

**without session fetch data**

```
<?php 
    $_SESSION['array1'] = array("zero","one","two");
    print_r($_SESSION['array1']);
?>
<form action="" method="post">
<input type="hidden" value="<?php echo implode(',',$_SESSION['array1']); ?>" name="detailCart"> 
<input type="submit" value="Detail" name="detail" class="detail">
</form>

<?php

    if (isset($_POST['detail'])) {
        session_start();
        echo $_POST['detailCart']; //string
        $array = explode(",",$_POST['detailCart']);
        echo '<br/>';
        echo $array[0];     
        echo '<br/>';
        echo $array[1];
        echo '<br/>';
        echo $array[2];

    }
?>
```

o/p

```
zero,one,two
zero
one
two
```

**another way**

```
 <?php 
        $_SESSION['array1'] = array("zero","one","two");
        print_r($_SESSION['array1']);
    ?>
    <form action="" method="post">

    <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['array1'][0] ?>" name="detailCart[0]"> 

    <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['array1'][1] ?>" name="detailCart[1]"> 

   <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['array1'][2] ?>" name="detailCart[2]"> 
    <input type="submit" value="Detail" name="detail" class="detail">
    </form>
```

> create a array of input field using same name with differ index
>   like name='name[0]',name='name[1]',name='name[2]'

**after submit**

```
<?php



     if (isset($_POST['detail'])) {
            session_start();
            echo $_POST['detailCart'][0];
             echo $_POST['detailCart'][1];
              echo $_POST['detailCart'][2];


        }
    ?>
```